Error TooExpensive when transferring fungible assets between parachains
I'm trying to transfer fungible assets between two parachains.
I'm using Westend relay chain, Westmint as first para and custom parachain as second para.
I launched my setup with zombienet and opened HRMP channels between paras.
After that I created fungible assets for parachain and make westmint assets sufficient throw calling this data 0x3e04e8030000020406020700e40b54022d023215011f00d43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d00d43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d00d43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d00d43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d040100.
After that I registered westmint asset on my custom parachain with this call 0x6f00c0070000010300a10f043205011f.
*Both parachains has pallet_assets id = 50 and created fungible asset id = 1984.
I minted some tokens on westmint for ALICE and trasferred some amount to BOB.
Created transaction to transfer tokens from westmint(id = 1000) to custom(id = 1001) para:


After submitting the transaction got this on westmint:

And this on custom parachain:

Also I changed Trader on my custom parachain to allow paying execution in other currencies, like this:
pub KUsdPerSecond: (xcm::v3::AssetId, u128, u128) = (MultiLocation::new(1, X3(Parachain(1000), PalletInstance(50), GeneralIndex(1984))).into(), default_fee_per_second() * 10, 0u128);
And Traders looks like this:
pub type Traders = ( FixedRateOfFungible<WUsdPerSecond, ()>, FixedRateOfFungible<KUsdPerSecond, ()>, FixedRateOfFungible<WndPerSecond, ()>, UsingComponents<WeightToFee, SelfReserve, AccountId, Balances, ToAuthor<Runtime>>, );
So, after all these steps I expected to see the transaction complete successfully, but I get the TooExpensive error on receiver chain.
Some time ago I have done this actions successfully, but now - no.
Perhaps I missed some little thing that I should do.
Thanks!
